# display cluster in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I have an image, `test3`:

[image]

I want to cluster points on the image.

My code:

```
[I,map]=imread('test3','bmp');
I = ~I;
imshow(I,map);
[m n]=size(I)
P = [];
for i=1:m    
    for j=1:n        
        if I(i,j)==1
            P = [P ; i j];        
        end
    end
end
size(P)
MON=P;
[IDX,ctrs] = kmeans(MON,3)
```

As I plot the clusters in the image, I also want to draw `IDX` and `ctrs` in the image.

How do I get an image with 3 new clusters, with each cluster a different color in the image.

Answer (score 1):

To generate the k-means clusters:

```
% locations of the black pixels
[I,map]=imread('test3','bmp'); I = ~I;
[ii,jj] = find(I==1);
P = [ii jj];

k = 3;
[IDX,ctrs] = kmeans(P,k);
```

To plot the points with different colors for each cluster:

```
cm = jet(k);
hold on
for ik=1:k,
    imap = IDX==ik;
    plot(P(imap,2),P(imap,1),'.','color',cm(:,ik));
end
axis image
axis ij
```

Add markers for the centers:

```
plot(ctrs(:,2),ctrs(:,1),'r*','markersize',10)
```

Result:

[image]

---

Or to make a color-coded image out of the cluster indexes:

```
kimg = zeros(size(I));
kimg(sub2ind(size(I),P(:,1),P(:,2))) = IDX;
cmap = [ones(1,3); jet(k)]
kimgRGB = ind2rgb(kimg+1,cmap);
imwrite(kimgRGB,'kimg.png')
```

Result:
[image]

Note that I have chosen the [`jet` colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html), but you can use any map you wish. Also, I have set the background to white (`ones(1,3)` is the color for index value 1).